# Full exception handling with HttpClient and timeouts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, timeout, httpclient

Im trying to build a wpf app that will act as a subnet scanner for certain devices. Some of the IP-addresses will reply with a response and others will timeout due to no reciever of the request. I'm doing all the requests async with Task.WhenAll() and when the HttpClient.Timeout is reached the Task is canceled as expected and the UI is still responsive. A while later the UI-freezes and HttpRequestExceptions and SocketExceptions appear from the thread that is already canceled. I did try to use a cancelationtoken aswell but with the same behaviour.
Can I cancel the full request from the HttpClient or can I handle the exceptions better in order for the UI not to freeze?

This is the code with an example of a url that does work and one that will not reply and timeout.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetStatus(string url)
        {
            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            try
            {
                var HTTPResponse = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
                string response = new System.IO.StreamReader(HTTPResponse).ReadToEnd();
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>
            {
                GetStatus("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search"),
                GetStatus("https://192.168.0.31")
            };

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
            }

            // Loop results
            var successfulTasks = tasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);

            // Process the results of successful tasks
            foreach (var successfulTask in successfulTasks)
            {
                // Get the return value inside the task
                string scanResult = ((Task<string>)successfulTask).Result;
                Debug.WriteLine(scanResult);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the exceptions coming from it. As can be seen the HttpRequestException and SocketException are coming after the Task is canceled.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in TestWPF.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 2 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStreamAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStreamAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TestWPF.MainWindow.GetStatus(String url)
   at TestWPF.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
[{"id":"9l6","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/9l6.jpg","width":720,"height":960}]
The thread 0x3a0c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Comment: When you say "the UI freezes", do you mean in the debugger, and you get a First Chance Exception popup? If so that's normal, and you can disable First Chance Exceptions for that exception type so thta it doesn't stop the debugger.

Comment: All the updates in the status log are updated as they should when the taskCanceledExceptions are coming from the timeouts. Say around 10 seconds later when the HttpRequestExceptions are coming the buttons are not clickable and the hoovering actions in the app are not responsive. It's the same with First Chansce Exception disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a deadlock in `ReadToEnd`. You need to use `await ReadToEndAsync`. You should also dispose the objects.

Furthermore, `client.Timeout` sometimes does not timeout if there is a DNS failure until 15 seconds are up. So use a `CancellationToken` instead.

Also you should use a single `HttpClient`, to avoid socket exhaustion.

```cs
static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };

public async Task<string> GetStatus(string url)
{
    using var cts = new cancellationTokeSource(2000);
    using var HTTPResponse = await _client.GetStreamAsync(url, cts.Token);
    using var sr = new StreamReader(HTTPResponse);
    string response = await sr.ReadToEndAsync(cts.Token);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Even with all these changes the TaskCanceledException is the one thats being handeled and the HttpRequestException and SocketException are freezing the Ui-thread. The cancelationToken is not canceling the request so it doesn't seem to solve it even if its the DNS-issue.